# WiFi connectivity keeps dropping

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, drivers

When using the internet, especially on sustained downloads, my internet connection keeps dropping, while my WiFi does stay connected. In `dmesg` I can see a lot of this:

```
[ 3583.785369] brcmsmac bcma0:1: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
[ 3585.501428] brcmsmac bcma0:1: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
[ 3585.518714] brcmsmac bcma0:1: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
[ 3598.207505] brcmsmac bcma0:1: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
[ 3598.532315] brcmsmac bcma0:1: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
```

This seems to always happen, but more frequently when the connection drops. Using `lspci` I can find my wireless card is a Broadcom BCM43224.

How do I fix this? It is very annoying to not be able to sustain a download for over a few seconds at times.

I am running Arch Linux with all packages updated.